# Error: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings

Tags: python, django

I am working a django project which uses django version 1.2.2. I am trying to runserver using manage.py or django-admin.py, but I am getting the error

```
Error: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings
```

The settings.py file is exists in the same directory where manage.py and wsgi.py exists. I tried it by passing the settings as an argument also

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings=settings.py
```

but still i get the same error that

```
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory
containing 'manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have
to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the
file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError
somehow.
```

I am using django 1.2 first time. Help will be appriciated

Comment: so what happens when you run `python settings.py`, does that report any errors?

Comment: You absolutely definitely should not be using Django 1.2, under any circumstances.

Comment: You are right @Martin, I had some errors in settings.py file. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable properly

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

or run django-admin as follow

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings=settings
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you run

./manage.py runserver